# Find files containing text, but report different part of it as result

Tags: grep, imap

I want to find all emails in my IMAP folders that contain a certain text (namely: that are sent to a certain email address). I already found out I can do so by using grep like so:

```
grep -rnw '~/users/example' -e "my@example.com"
```

This returns either the matched text or the name of the file (with `-l`). But what I really need for my task is to know the "Title" of the email file that was found.

```
/home/example/users/example/.Archives.2013/cur/1364614080.4080.example.com:2,Sa
/home/example/users/example/.Archives.2013/cur/1385591317.91317.example.com:2,RSa
/home/example/users/example/.Archives.2013/cur/1358235054.35054.example.com:2,S
/home/example/users/example/.Archives.2013/cur/1358445545.45545.example.com:2,S
/home/example/users/example/.Archives.2013/cur/1453119248.M330746P8611.example.com,S=6761,W=6915:2,S
```

So, I somehow need to find the files based on the grep above, but the result that is listed should be a different part of that same file (maybe with regex?).

How can I go about this?

Comment: can you add an example how the file looks when there is match? one idea is to pass matched files to another program... `grep -rFwlZ '~/users/example'  -e 'my@example.com' | xargs -0 <some command>` or may be use find+awk combo.. `-F` option for literal string matching, no regex here

Comment: `grep` is not the right tool for this, since both the address and the text can be encoded in various ways. You could use a mail client such as `mutt`, but that's only good for interactive use. You need to write a program (perhaps in Perl or Python) around an IMAP client.

Comment: @Sundeep I added an example output with `-l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `formail` (shipped with `procmail`):

```
find ~/users/example -type f -exec sh -c '
  for email do
    formail -x to -x cc < "$email" |
      grep -qF my@example.com &&
      formail -cx subject < "$email"
  done' sh {} +
```

That is, for each email file

- extract the `To` and `Cc` headers
- search for `my@example.com` in there
- if found, extract the `Subject` header and print it on one line (with `-c`).

Comment: This works if you want to search messages by addresses, but not if you want to search the body (since `formail` doesn't decode attachments etc.).

Comment: @SatoKatsura. True, if the OP had a different question, that would call for a different answer. Not sure it's worth going into the details on how to parse and decode emails. Given the subject of the question, `formail` already goes beyond what is asked.

Comment: This works perfectly fine for my needs. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

What is the "Title" of a file, the path or name? Use the --files-with-matches option or -l to list matched filenames. If you search only fixed strings instead of regular expressions, speed up the process with -F

```
grep -F -r -l my@example.com ~/users/example
```

Do match other content of the file, grep the list of found files (fgrep is the same as grep -F):

```
fgrep -rl my@example.com ~/users/example | xargs grep '^Subject:'
```

Hint: many commands stops the parsing of options at the first argument without minus-character. So all options are should be called first.

Comment: This doesn't work, since the headers can be encoded (cf. RFC 2047 and RFC 2231).

Answer (score 1):

With `mutt`:

```
muff -f ~/users/example/.Archives.2013
```

(assuming that's a maildir folder). And within `mutt`, type <kbd>l</kbd> (lowercase `L`).

At the `Limit to messages matching:` prompt, enter:

```
~C my@example.com
```

(though strictly speaking, as it's a regexp, it should be `~C 'my@example\.com'` for the `.` to be matched literally).

Or start `mutt` as:

```
mutt -f ~/users/example/.Archives.2013 -e 'push "l ~C my@example.com"'
```

`~C` searches in the `To:` and `Cc:` headers.

Check [the manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#patterns) for the search syntax.

To search in more than one mailbox at once, there are several mail indexers that you can use (within `mutt` or not). See https://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/UseCases/SearchingMail for instance.

Comment: This is fine if you want to get the results interactively, but it isn't useful from a script.